# How do I write code with a separate variable that keeps track of whether the 'break' statement was encountered? Python

Tags: python, break

I came across the below article, "Hidden Gems of Python," and the writer of the article stated the following in the last paragraph of the article: "separate variable that keeps track of whether the *break* statement was encountered." I'm unable to make contact with the writer of the article to ask him to provide sample code with a separate variable that keeps track of whether the *break* statement was encountered.
Would someone please provide sample code with a separate variable that keeps track of whether the *break* statement was encountered?
And please read the article below before providing answers; the last paragraph in the article begins with "One could argue..." Thank you.

"Hidden Gems of Python"
by: Charudatta Manwatkar

For-Else Loop

In Python, you can add an else clause to a for loop. The else clause will be triggered only if no break statement was encountered within the body of the loop during execution.

```
my_list = ['some', 'list', 'containing', 'five', 'elements']

min_len = 3

for element in my_list:
    if len(element) < min_len:
        print(f'Caught an element shorter than {min_len} letters')
        break

else:
    print(f'All elements at least {min_len} letters long')
```

Output: All elements at least 3 letters long

Notice that the else is indented at the level of for and not at the level of if. Here, no element has length shorter than 3. So, the break statement will never be encountered. Hence, the else clause will get triggered (after the for loop is executed) and print the output shown above.

One could argue that this could be achieved using a separate variable that keeps track of whether the break statement was encountered. And perhaps it would also be less confusing for the next person reading the code. Still, it’s good to know, I guess.

Comment: `broke = False` ... `if ...: broke = True; break` ... `if broke: ...`…!?

Comment: Correct, ``for..else`` is not a very common construct, but it's well documented if you someone cares to actually read the python docs. So what's your actual question?

Comment: @Mike Scotty...the question is, "Would someone please provide an example of a variable that keeps track of whether the 'break' statement was encountered?" Thanks.

Comment: you sure need break or you need continue ?? all elements are greater than the min_len you specified, it will never go into the if block.

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list = ['some', 'list', 'containing', 'five', 'elements']

min_len = 3
break_encountered=True
for element in my_list:
    if len(element) < min_len:
        print(f'Caught an element shorter than {min_len} letters')
        break

else:
    break_encountered=False
    print(f'All elements at least {min_len} letters long')

if break_encountered:
    print("A break is encountered")
else:
    print("no break encountered")
```

It is what you want ?

Comment: I think the article meant using a variable *instead* of `else`.

Comment: @CrazyChucky ...Oooh, I think you're right because I finally made contact with the writer of the article, and he provided me code showing a separate variable that keeps track of whether the 'break' statement was encountered, and it was without else. He also added the code to his article.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['so', 'list', 'containing', 'five', 'elements']

min_len = 3

num_of_breaks = {}

for element in my_list:
    if len(element) < min_len:
        print(f'Caught an element shorter than {min_len} letters')
        num_of_breaks[element] = "Break was encountered for this element"
        break

else:
    print(f'All elements at least {min_len} letters long')

track = print('No break occured') if len(num_of_breaks) == 0 else print("Break occured for: ", num_of_breaks)
```

The first element was reduced to 2 characters to see effect

Answer (score 0):

Perseverance pays off once again!!!

I finally made contact with the writer of the aforementioned article, and requested he provide me sample code showing a separate variable that keeps track of whether the *break* statement was encountered. The following code he provided is basically the same as the answers I received here in Stack Overflow - thanks, Stack Overflow members! - and he also added the code to his article:

```
my_list = ['some', 'list', 'containing', 'five', 'elements']

min_len = 3

no_break = True

for element in my_list:
    if len(element) < min_len:
        print(f'Caught an element shorter than {min_len} letters')
        no_break = False
        break

if no_break:
    print(f'All elements at least {min_len} letters long')
```

Although, the code would no longer be a for-else loop.